# React-Native App Crashes (Test Flight) on Device but runs fine in simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I can't seem to figure this one out.

My react-native app runs fine in the ios simulator but crashes when installed on a device via TestFlight.

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x19c00d86c __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1b1028c50 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   CamexAppraiser                  0x102772a6c RCTFatal + 668 (RCTAssert.m:145)
3   CamexAppraiser                  0x1027ef3c4 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatal:stack:exceptionId:suppressRedBox:] + 492 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:76)
4   CamexAppraiser                  0x1027efdfc -[RCTExceptionsManager reportException:] + 1536 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:145)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x19c0128f4 __invoking___ + 148
6   CoreFoundation                  0x19bee9df8 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 448 (NSForwarding.m:3389)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x19beea3cc -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 80 (NSForwarding.m:3495)
8   CamexAppraiser                  0x1027a287c -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 460 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:584)
9   CamexAppraiser                  0x1027a4a10 facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&) + 244 (RCTNativeModule.mm:114)
10  CamexAppraiser                  0x1027a4774 operator() + 44 (RCTNativeModule.mm:75)
11  CamexAppraiser                  0x1027a4774 invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 88 (RCTNativeModule.mm:67)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x19bc0024c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1454)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x19bc01db0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x19bc0910c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 580 (inline_internal.h:2548)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x19bc09c5c _dispatch_lane_invoke + 408 (queue.c:3862)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x19bc13d78 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 708 (queue.c:6601)
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1e7abd814 _pthread_wqthread + 276 (pthread.c:2211)
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1e7ac476c start_wqthread + 8
```

Comment: You need to search for your stuck trace "key" errors. What a real device gives you it's what you should watch out for, simulator it's just a simulation

Comment: @vpoltave not too sure what you mean here?

Comment: You have to google something like that: https://www.google.com/search?q=RCTExceptionsManager+reportFatal%3Astack%3AexceptionId%3AsuppressRedBox%3A&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUA888UA889&oq=RCTExceptionsManager+reportFatal%3Astack%3AexceptionId%3AsuppressRedBox%3A&aqs=chrome..69i57.200j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I notice the crash log references files on my local computer. but the crash report came from a test flight install on my phone.

Comment: @JamesMurgatroyd can you post those logs as well? A common error is either (a) your Xcode is pointing to a localhost url for React Native or (b) you reference images/assets in your code that never actually got bundled into your app on build.

Comment: @I'mJoeToo have a look here at the full report. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/674465?page=1#663354022

Comment: @JamesMurgatroyd did you find any solution for this. I am facing the same, it references local node_modules path in TestFlight build. If you able to fix it then please add it in answer section. Lots of people will get benefit from it. Thanks